# How does this correlated Subquery works

Tags: sql

how does this query works ?

```
select Salary 
from Example e1 
where 3 = 
       (select count(distinct Salary) 
        from Example e2 
        where e1.Salary <= e2.Salary);
```

the SRC table

```
   ID  Name   Salary      DEP

    1   A   100.0000    AB
    2   b   10.0000     BC
    3   c   10.0000     BC
    4   d   50.0000     CD
```

the result is 10.

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure you select "Where 3 ="? seems odd - Maybe you mean "Where ID ="?

Comment: This depends on the DBMS you're using and even its current state (presence of indices, their types, etc.) Whichever database you're using, it should give you the ability to see the query's execution plan.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think it should return 10, 10.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . Correct.  I read the condition backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finds the distinct count of different salaries, for each row in the outer query, where the `Salary` is <strike>less</strike> greather than or equal to the `Salary` in the row from the outer query. Finally, it then only returns rows from the outer query if the sub query returned exactly 3 different salaries.

Ugh, I'm not sure that clears anything up any more than reading the query itself does, but I tried. :P

So, for example, if the table looked like this:

```
Salary
======
10000
20000
30000
40000
50000
60000
```

When the outer query is evaluating `10000` it's not going to be returned, but when it's evaluating `40000` it will be. In fact, the way it's written, that's the **only row** that would be returned.

One problem with the query is that it's counting itself too because it's not filtering itself out with any id.

Comment: But then it shouldn't return 10, it should return 50

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, I too got mixed up with the wording and I've edited it; sorry.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, it should return 10, 10.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is easiest to understand what is happening by evaluating row by row. The sub select evaluates to:

100 -> 1

10 -> 3

50 -> 2

The predicate `3 = ( select ... )` therefore evaluates to true for the two rows with salary 10, so the answer should be:

10

10